# Find All Complex solutions for $z^3+3i\bar{z}=0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

**Find All Complex solutions for $z^3+3i \bar z =0$.**
I tried substituting $z=a+bi$ and simplifying as much as I can
and this is what I ended up with: $a^3-2b^2a+3b+i(3ba^2-b^3+3a)=0$.

I just did not understand how do I get the values of $z$ from this equation

Comment: Did you try using $z=r \exp(i\theta)$ and solving for $r$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Or, take your result, then solve for both the real and imaginary parts vanishing

Comment: Do you mean $\bar{z}$ instead of $z^-$?

Comment: yeah i meant z conjugate

Comment: $-2b^2a$ must be $-3b^2a$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $z^3 =-3i\bar{z}$ we have $\bar{z}^3 = 3iz$. So pluging $\bar{z} ={iz^3\over 3}$ in second equation we get$${-iz^9\over 27} = 3iz\implies z^9+81z=0$$

So $z_9=0$ and then $$z^8=-81\implies z_k=\sqrt{3}(\cos{(2k-1)\pi\over 8}+i\sin{(2k-1)\pi\over 8}) $$
$k\in\{1,2,...8\}$

Comment: The roots of unity here have an error. The even values of $k$ should be discarded, instead using only odd values of $k$ but all the way up to $15$.

Comment: Recall that these are roots of $-1$, not of unity. If you take $\exp(i k\pi/8)^8=\exp(ik\pi)$, you want this to always be $-1$, so you need odd $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $z=r e^{i\theta}$; the equation becomes
$$r^3 e^{3 i\theta}+3i re^{-i\theta}=0.$$ One immediate solution has $r=0$, i.e., $z=0$. Otherwise, we only need to solve
$$r^2 e^{4 i\theta}+3i =0.$$

We rewrite this as
$$r^2 e^{4 i\theta}=3 e^{3\pi i/2}.$$ We find that $r=\sqrt{3}$ for the four possibilities $e^{ i\theta}= e^{3\pi i/8}$, $e^{ i\theta}= ie^{3\pi i/8}$, $e^{ i\theta}= -e^{3\pi i/8}$, and $e^{ i\theta}= -ie^{3\pi i/8}$, found from the four fourth roots of unity. These yield $\theta\in(3\pi/8,7\pi/8,11\pi/8,15\pi/8)$.

Comment: We still did not learn to solve the problem using z=re^iθ, so i don't think i can use this as an answer

Comment: Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: @QuadStarling246 why? best way...

Comment: @QuadStarling246 What if, instead, you multiply the equation throughout by $z,$ and rearrange, getting $z^4 = -3i|z|^2$: is that compatible with the methods you have been taught? It gives you $|z| = \sqrt3,$ so $z = \sqrt3u$ where $|u| = 1,$ so $\bar{u} = 1/u,$ whence $u^4 = -i,$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a commentary on all of the existing answers, rather than a suggested method of solution. It seems fashionable to state that there are $9$ solutions, when in reality there are $5$ solutions $z$ to the equation $$z^3-3i\overline z = 0$$
Writing $z=x+iy$, we obtain the following polynomial equations by taking real and imaginary parts of the given equation:
\begin{align*}
&x^3-3xy^2+3y = 0 \\
&3x^2y+3x-y^3 = 0
\end{align*}
By [Bézout's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), the corresponding projective curves have $9$ intersections, counting multiplicity. However, we are seeking *real* solutions $(x,y)$ in the affine plane, so there could be fewer than $9$ solutions to the equation $z^3-3i\overline z = 0$.
By [standard polynomial algebra](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GrobnerBasis%5B%7Bx%5E3%E2%88%923xy%5E2%2B3y%2C+3x%5E2y%2B3x%E2%88%92y%5E3%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%7D%5D), this system is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
&9x-8y^7+51y^3 = 0 \\
&64y^9-432y^5+81y=0
\end{align*}
Factoring $y$ out of the second equation and performing the substitution $Y=y^4$, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
64Y^2-432Y+81
\end{equation*}
The roots are $$Y = \frac{27}8 \pm \frac94\sqrt2$$
These are positive real numbers, and so the solutions for $y$ are
\begin{equation*}
y = 0, \pm\left(\frac{27}8 \pm \frac94\sqrt2\right)^{1/4}
\end{equation*}
For each $y$, the coordinate $x$ is uniquely determined and real. This means that there are $5$ solutions to the equation,
$$z^3-3i\overline z = 0$$

Comment: This is the correct answer (mine has been updated accordingly - the error across the board is taking equations beyond their definitions: for example, mine let $r$ become negative in the polar decomposition $z=r e^{i\theta}$)

Answer (score 0):

You let $z=a+bi$ and the system of equations to solve is: $a^3-3ab^2+3b=0$ and $3ba^2-b^3+3a=0$. If you multiply the first equation by $-a$ and the second by $b$ and then add the resulting equations you get $a^4+b^4=6a^2b^2$. Let $m=\frac{b}{a}$. Then, $$m^4-6m^2+1=0.$$ The solution of this equation is: $m=\tan(\frac{3\pi}{8}+\frac{k\pi}{2})$ where $k=0,1,2,3$. Hence, we found the Arguments (angles) of the 4 solutions. The other 4 Arguments can be found by formula $\pi-\theta$ from these Arguments, since $\tan(\pi-\theta)=-\tan\theta$ satisfies the equation too.

To find the magnitudes of them, multiply the first equation by $a$ and the second by $b$ and then add the resulting equations you get $a^2+b^2=\frac{6ab}{b^2-a}$. Then, since $b=ma$, we have $|z|=\sqrt\frac{6m}{m^2-1}$. We find out that $\sqrt\frac{6m}{m^2-1}=\sqrt{3}$ for all $m$ values we found above. I checked by WolframAlpha trying to prove by hand...

The solution $z=0$ could be found by polar method.

Comment: Ooops. I had found only four of them.

Comment: Omg we forget zero too.